# Using GetAttributeValue<T> Dynamically in CRM Online

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have C# code running to compare pre and post-images in CRM to determine if a field changed (long story short: external process I can't control is updating every field on a record every time, even if fields haven't changed). I want to use the CRM GetAttributeValue(attributeName) to do it, but I want to do it dynamically when I may not know the field name. So, for example, I want to do this:

```
// pretend the value of firstname is not hard-coded but submitted on a form    
// (not really on a form, but just know it's not hard-coded like it is below.)
string fieldToCheck = "firstname"; 
if (preImage.GetAttributeValue<T>(fieldToCheck) != postImage.GetAttributeValue<T>(fieldToCheck))
{
  // do something here. I've tried something like the below, but it doesn't work with error "t is a variable but used like a type". 
  Type t = preImage.Attributes[fieldToCheck].GetType();
  var val = preImage.GetAttributeValue<t>(fieldToCheck);

}
```

The problem I'm having is that `<T>` could be different depending on the value of `fieldToCheck`. In the case of firstname it would be `<string>`, in the case of new_DateOpened it would be `<DateTime>`, etc. I must be having a brain spasm because I should be able to figure out how to dynamically get the value of T, but can't.

Comment: Since you're using var why don't you just use GetType ? to determine the type of data you have in fieldToCheck?

Comment: Modified the code. fieldToCheck will always be a string. It's simply the name of the attribute in CRM that I want to get.

Answer (score 1):

A generic type parameter `T` is not equal to an instance of type `Type`. You can go from type param `T -> Type` using `typeof(T)`, but not from `Type -> T` easily. Type T must be known at compile time normally.

You CAN apparently do this with reflection per here ([How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)):

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Entity).GetMethod("GetAttributeValue");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
generic.Invoke(preImage, fieldToCheck); // and postImage
```

Comment: I support this answer, but for some reason, he is pushing the type to be var as an anonymous type. Don't know why.

Comment: You mean when he did `var fieldToCheck = "firstname"`? `var` didn't imply an anonymous type in that instance, it implied an inferred type of string.

Comment: yep cause of the " " but check his comment on top. Pretend that the code is not hard coded.

Comment: fieldToCheck will always be a string. It represents the name of an attribute on an entity in Microsoft CRM. The attribute that name represents, though, may be of any type: string, date/time, numeric, a CRM option set, etc., which is why I don't know what the type will be. I'm going down this route because an external process that I can't control updates every field even if the values haven't changed. This is causing my CRM workflow to fire because the email field value changed when it really hasn't changed - hence me using the pre & post images to compare.

Comment: Jeff I would use the answer by @Henk-van-Boeijen if that works. I would avoid reflection whenever possible due to the performance implications.

Comment: That was my inclination, but I do have a follow-up question on his answer.

Answer (score 1):

For most (if not all) attribute types you can rely on the common `Equals(object o)` method. This also works for the attributes based on classes `EntityReference`, `OptionSetValue` and `Money`.

You only need to do an extra check on `null` values. (When an attribute has a `null` value in the system it will not be present in the attribute collection of a pre- or post-image.)

```
public static bool IsAttributeModified(string attributeName, Entity preImage, Entity postImage)
{
    object preValue;

    if (preImage.Attributes.TryGetValue(attributeName, out preValue))
    {
        object postValue;
        return !postImage.Attributes.TryGetValue(attributeName, out postValue) || !preValue.Equals(postValue);
    }

    return postImage.Attributes.ContainsKey(attributeName);
}
```